# Contact emails keep going to spam folder for almost everyone for Joomla component

Tags: joomla

We are using a Joomla component and all the messages for the "contact this advertiser" web form go directly to spam.  We have tested many email accounts and have made every change I can think of.  Any assistance would be great.

**here is the page where the web form is:**

http://www.shopforbiz.com/buy-a-business/ad/restaurants,26/franchise-sub-shop,31

**Here is the email header information:**

```
Delivered-To: adammotta@gmail.com   
Received: by 10.194.27.195 with SMTP id v3csp56291wjg;    
Thu, 7 Aug 2014 06:01:33 -0700 (PDT)    
X-Received: by 10.68.113.133 with SMTP id iy5mr17521168pbb.135.1407416493076;    
Thu, 07 Aug 2014 06:01:33 -0700 (PDT)    
Return-Path: <inquiry@shopforbiz.com>    
Received: from see.seekmomentum.com (see.seekmomentum.com. [198.57.217.77])   
by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ym5si3469643pab.6.2014.08.07.06.01.32   
for <adammotta@gmail.com>    
(version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);    
Thu, 07 Aug 2014 06:01:32 -0700 (PDT)    
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of inquiry@shopforbiz.com designates 198.57.217.77 as permitted sender) client-ip=198.57.217.77;    
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;   
spf=pass (google.com: domain of inquiry@shopforbiz.com designates 198.57.217.77 as 
permitted sender) smtp.mail=inquiry@shopforbiz.com    
Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1]:35995 helo=www.shopforbiz.com)    
by see.seekmomentum.com with esmtpa (Exim 4.82)   
(envelope-from <inquiry@shopforbiz.com>)    
id 1XFNJz-0003RC-Jy   
for adammotta@gmail.com; Thu, 07 Aug 2014 09:01:31 -0400    
Date: Thu, 7 Aug 2014 09:01:31 -0400        
To: adammotta@gmail.com    
From: Shop For Biz <inquiry@shopforbiz.com>    
Reply-To: inquiry@shopforbiz.com   
Subject: New Inquiry from ShopforBiz    
Message-ID: <18888aba9485a3ef865449febf2667c2@www.shopforbiz.com>    
X-Priority: 3    
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.6 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)    
MIME-Version: 1.0    
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8    
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit    
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report    
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - see.seekmomentum.com   
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - seekmomentum.com    
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]    
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - shopforbiz.com    
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: see.seekmomentum.com: authenticated_id: inquiry@shopforbiz.com    
X-Source:     
X-Source-Args:     
X-Source-Dir:     
From user: adam    
User email: adamd@yaho.com    
Your advertisement ''Carry Out Chicken, Ribs & Pizza'' enquiry 
test
```

Comment: Assuming this component is a 3rd party component, have you tried contacting the developer of the extension? It's their job to provide support for you

Comment: how did you setup the email? ie. sendmail or smtp? SPF looks in order, try adding DKIM authentication too. I also notice that spf `v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:198.57.217.77 ~all` allow soft fail for all other that may also be the case, remove `~all` if the webserver for domain `shopforbiz.com` which is the IP `198.57.217.77` are the only sender.

Comment: How are the emails being sent?  If you're using an SMTP server not provided by your email host to relay emails the lack of proper DNS records is most likely the culprit.